# Retrieve data on mouse click in Mayavi

Tags: python, python-2.7, mouseclick-event, mayavi

I have developed a code in which scatter points are plotted and on clicking on a particular scatter point I am able to add text/label using text3d. But now i want to recover or retrieve that data from any point on that graph using on_mouse_pick callback  and print that data in console. I want this in Mayavi/Mayavi2. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is from http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_select_red_balls.html example.

```
glyphs = mlab.points3d(x, y, z, s, colormap="RdYlBu", scale_factor=1, scale_mode='none')
glyph_points = glyphs.glyph.glyph_source.glyph_source.output.points.to_array()

print(len(s))

def picker_callback(picker):
    if picker.actor in glyphs.actor.actors:
        point_id = picker.point_id//glyph_points.shape[0]
        if point_id != -1:
            print("{}:".format(point_id))
            print("({} {} {}) ".format(x[point_id],y[point_id],z[point_id]))

picker = figure.on_mouse_pick(picker_callback)
mlab.show()
```

Hope that helps sb, the division to get point index in array is quite funny ;)

Comment: Yeah the point index is funny! Thanks for fixing getting the index in the example to use floor division.